# My Mac Mini HD been wiped out

Tags: hard-drive, macos

Here is the scenario: I was bouncing music and got a warning Macintosh HD is almost full! By the time I empty the trash my my froze.
So I restart it and that infinite white progress bar below the gorgeous Apple never end progressing.

I reboot in single user and tried a fsck check but in seem to only check for OS X base system which appear OK.

Tried the verbose and got stuck within a pause.

Then tried to reach for my users in terminal within recovery booting and there was nothing there, no users, no hidden files, nothing but a .forward and a Library. I didn't cried !

I'm ok with the reality of a Hardware failure.
I'm not so ok with the fact of loosing music that I made that came out of the blue from spontaneous inspiration. So for this last part, I will do everything necessary to get to those files.

So I started my OLD MB Pro (2007) and FW target boot from it.
Here's what disk Utility have to tell about it;

[image: Disk utility lecture of my Mac-mini from my MBP]

Any cue is more then welcome

Comment: Is that a Fusion Drive?

Comment: I'm wondering if those _incompatible format_  are in there because Disk Utilty on my old Mac cannot read new disk format ?

Comment: Fusion Drive is supported starting with OS X Mountain Lion (2012).

Comment: @Nikita probably but in 2 Volumes ?

Comment: '/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme  *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:         EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:         Apple_CoreStorage Internal Drive          121.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:         Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk0s3'

Comment: '/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   0:          GUID_partition_scheme             *1.0 TB     disk1
   1:          EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Internal Drive          999.3 GB   disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk1s3'

Comment: /dev/disk2 (disk image):
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +2.1 GB     disk2
   1:                  Apple_HFS OS X Base System        2.0 GB     disk2s1
/dev/disk3 (internal, virtual):
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +1.1 TB     disk3
Logical Volume on disk1s2, disk0s2
            DBB5212A-2FA1-4EF4-B282-862BD5AD19A5
            Unencrypted Fusion Drive

Comment: Well that's the idea of a Fusion Drive, isn't it? You get two devices—an SSD and an HDD—in a single volume. Looks like you have a 1TB fusion drive and your MacBook doesn't recognize it since it seems to be running 10.5 Leopard, not 10.8 Mountain Lion.

Comment: I just don't know Fusion drive architecture, but to make it short I see that there is a An Apple boot recovery HD. Does this mean that there is still life on my HD ?

Comment: I don't know how the internet recovery works but I supposed that if my HD is dead it just cannot take room on my HD no matter what !

Comment: There's a recovery partition and there's [internet recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314), two different things. Internet recovery doesn't use your disk and stores it's image in memory.

Comment: That's what i'm trying to figure out. If I can see that recovery partition it means that my HD still work somehow

Answer (score 1):

Use [Internet Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) on your Mac Mini and try repairing `Macintosh HD` with `Disk Utility`.
If that fails to fix the boot issue, connect your Mac Mini in target disk mode to a mac running OS X 10.8 or later and see if you can at least copy the files off your Fusion Drive.
In the future, set up a [Time Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Machine_(OS_X)).

Comment: I tried Internet recovery, it don't see the disk :-( And unfortunately I was working on too much big files so I needed to redo my rules for my TimeMachine but this happen before I had the chance to do it.

Comment: Does anyone know a way fix that blinded partition ?

Comment: Without the disk utility app